# google app engine denying google sql connection

Tags: mysql, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my web application to google sql. The app is running and getting deployed on appspot without database access. However when I try to deploy enable google cloud sql it is giving me following error:
[image]

I am to access the cloud sql using mysql command line prompt. Can anybody help what am I doing wrong here. I think there is a problem with appid. I create an application name cfsdonuts on appengine and gave it the access to sql instance. I create the application on eclipse with same appid (because eclipse was not allowing to choose from existing id's not it was allowing me to create new app id at the time of project creation. When I deploy the application on app engine the name comes as http://1-dot-cfsdonuts.appspot.com/. Should I use this name?

Comment: Did you create a root password on your Cloud SQL instance?  There isn't one by default, you have to specifically make it -- see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#mysqlaccess-root

Comment: When I login using mysql command line client it asks for the password . So yes I created it @Alex Martelli

Comment: `1-dot-cfsdonuts.appspot.com` is just the way `1.cfsdonuts.appspot.com` is spelled (version 1 of `cfsdonuts`) to avoid subdomains and thus allowing use of https -- shouldn't be your problem.  But what exactly is the name of the Google Cloud SQL instance within your `cfsdonuts` **project** (name of the app engine app shdn't matter, only the names of the project & instance)?  `cfsdonuts.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance` doesn't look like a valid cloud SQL instance name (perhaps it's just how eclipse presents it?  I don't use eclipse...).

Comment: Note that App Engine connects to Cloud SQL using the `root@localhost` user, which by default has no password. This is _not_ the same user that you use to connect from your local machine using the mysql client (because you don't connect  from `localhost`). Make sure that you are using the appropriate password from App Engine.

Comment: by default the password for root user is blank. I changed it to "root" which i give when I access from my sql client. When I try to associate cloud sql from eclipse, it also asks for the instance name, database,username and password, which I gave same as I gave in client. One difference is while connecting from mysql client I give the ipv6 address of the sql instance, in eclipse it doesn't ask for that, I am not sure whether this is the cause? @Juan Enrique Muñoz Zolotoochin

Comment: @AmeyJain, I still don't see your SQL instance **name** -- e.g what does `gcloud sql instances list --project cfsdonuts` show you?

Comment: "cfsdonuts:cfsdatabase" this is written as my sql instance id in developer console. I am sorry but I am not figure out where should type this command.  @Alex Martelli

Comment: The `gcloud` command works from a Terminal (command prompt, in Windows) -- once you've properly installed it as per https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/ .  I personally find it indispensable.  Anyway, `gcloud` or lack thereof is not your problem at hand, so let me try to dig deeper about the latter -- I'll be back!

Comment: Darn -- I'm at home for the long weekend and I can't explore your problem from here (for some reason it seems I can't SSH into work).  Sorry -- I'll look again on Tuesday when I'm physically back in the office!

Comment: Hi @AmeyJain, finally got to look it up -- `cfsdonuts:cfsdatabase` is `SUSPENDED` with `suspension_reason: BILLING_ISSUE`.  Unfortunately I can't dig any deeper about the billing issue for privacy reasons, but please look into it and if you don't understand the problem mail https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-discuss or even better check out https://support.google.com/cloud/topic/4356361?hl=en&ref_topic=3340598

Comment: Hi @Alex Martelli. I stopped the instance as it was increasing the bill. I have started it again. But I dont see a way to connect to it programatically. The code that google provides is not working with ipv6 address. I also created ipv4 address for the instance but that also didn't worked. this is the address 2001:4860:4864:1:32f7:453d:d3:f7b0 if you want anything else please let me know. I will also browse though these groups in the mean time. Thanks